# Check JWT exp field by comparing longs

Tags: java, timestamp, jwt

I want to check if my JWT token is still valid(exp is still in the future) but I am not sure I did it the right way.

My checking function -

```
public boolean checkForValidExpField(String jwtToken) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
    //split by .
    String[] split_string = jwtToken.split("\\.");
    //get body
    String base64EncodedBody = split_string[1];
    Base64 base64Url = new Base64(true);

    String body = new String(base64Url.decode(base64EncodedBody));
    //body to json
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(body);
    //get exp 
    String exp = actualObj.get(JWT_EXP_KEY).asText(); //JWT_EXP_KEY = exp
    //to long
    long expLong = Long.parseLong(exp) * 1000;
    //get current TS
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //check
    return expLong >= currentTime; 
}
```

And a simple main for testing -

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
    JWTCheckerUtil u = new JWTCheckerUtil();
    //expired
    String token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlEwWXpOVFkzTWtZeFJUbERORFEzT0RNME5VSTBORFk1TmtRNFF6STNNekF6TVRWRU1VTkVNQSJ9.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.EIsAuwEA9jT5KNjCGfGoWyfu9P2-jwhGy_lDZVjwmi33p7do_0L7bXU71gjTipZ9usHCB-eOILRNUGybEe4ge9PpHg3C3SZEsPtYG80uThItbyKTwyc80Yeq-x_V7s4g3eq8PzAbRR4N_H_q3-urnLXNumT4qc7eV0IkD1ad468Ez5sLOii0zCOSx_Gsaos_xbz3zhs_u0D1YS8kWh_nPbWdv1kxa45eM-bzH7ePTkci_KHkJZ_6MZ3MrEBswHgmUSsgtqS9mJPve6MtgR0qEBla1dfHuW4uxEuWdWWCkyt5JBTfYuGodt3KkSha9URzPdugWTn8eb5gCZRYvj5jBQ";
    System.out.println(u.checkForValidExpField(token));
    //not expired
    String expToken = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlEwWXpOVFkzTWtZeFJUbERORFEzT0RNME5VSTBORFk1TmtRNFF6STNNekF6TVRWRU1VTkVNQSJ9.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.lcciBBHyuCAkFmmUbMje8XeRFDCiPFpS0R0gdAhN-2SdY_RkawAbjZSLnH74ro8eU1vEsOuNQr1dtBYUSgMuJYVUb1YQBBQLtYWa5yasoX1AAOKZo5Gn3H5xf9WHajsIVAuew-2k6nh9088v334Agb7yd9JaziOm9r3XZeedlHl9hBC18SRoNrfH8oSoP8BLfCt0Okcse1KlnfYfjEAXvNT5nJ80tznIKOv1SR6P5YEXLdRNvXE-xNLnwpAge2I96b9ZhPaDrRZOh-fntkciWtwGn5woYCfzt5G3ooT6J2aVdaT6hfkka5pOoBR2UZzI9X75xpWZoMn4cbzwIJeE-Q";
    System.out.println(u.checkForValidExpField(expToken));
}
```

Is that the right way to check only the exp field? I wrote it myself so I just want to be sure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exp` claim (and other time related claims like `nbf`) are numeric dates:

The [JWT documentation (RFC)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-2) defines the numeric date:

> A JSON numeric value representing the number of seconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC until the specified UTC date/time, ignoring leap seconds.

So you can indeed compare the long values like shown in your code,
or subtract the current time from the exp value to get the remaining time.